# Copy text from "joined cell" to another sheet's smaller joined cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

Normally, text appears in the cell when it contains a reference to another (=Sheet1!A1 will show the contents of sheet A1) However, if both target and destination are joined cells, and the target is larger then the destination, then the only text that appears is the command "=Sheet1!A1" in the destination.
Example:
Target: (from sheet 1)

Client: XXX Company
Site Address    120 Center Street

Destination: (Sheet 2)

Client:        ='Main Info'!B1:G1              Date:   04/03/13
Site Address:       120 Center Street

Short of redesigning the forms, is there a way around this?

---

*Image not added by OP:*

[image: SU577553 example]

Comment: Agree with pnuts that you need to provide more info and an example. What you describe is not normal Excel behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, select an entry in Sheet2, Formulas > Formula Auditing and click on Show Formulas.